# Get value from cell and use it as MAX value for auto-increment in a macro

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, macros

Cell C13 auto increments by 1 on print.
I'm only using cell C13 to auto increment, but i have cell E13 = has a Linked value from Sheet 3. I would like to have the E13 value set as MAX increment for C13 in the following VBA :

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)
Dim i As Long
Cancel = True
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show
With Sheets("Sheet3")
    For i = 1 To .Range("B22").Value
        .Range("C13").Value = .Range("C13").Value + 1
        .PrintOut
    Next i
End With
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Edited source and cell names. Issue is having the macro to work on the Sheet3 give a debugger error 9.

Comment: do you want just don't increase above A15, or also cancel print in that case?

Comment: @Máté Juhász
Dont increase past A15, there is no need to cancel, just limit incrementation

Comment: this isn't fair. This is a different question then your original one. Please ask another question to fix your code, then come back here once you have a working code and ready to solve the original issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent increase beyond value in A15 amend your addition:

```
.Range("A4").Value = Min(.Range("A4").Value + 1, .Range("A15").Value)
```

Comment: I'm checking it right now

Comment: Debugger said problem with SUB ? line 
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)

Comment: Did it work before applying my modification?

Comment: It did work on my base example but actually it now returns : Debugger code 9 : for line With Sheets("Sheet3"), i'm a bit confused....

Comment: I updated my question to reflect the code im using now